# Bees with Machine Guns syntax error involving paramiko. (self._close(async=True))

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, paramiko

I'm trying to set up Bees with Machine Guns and noticed that regardless of the command for the bees I'm getting a syntax error inside the paramiko library:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_file.py", line 66
self._close(async=True)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thoughts on how to handle this?/how to get Bees with Machine Guns running? I was looking at https://gist.github.com/mattheworiordan/1892979 but I don't think thats for the same issue.

Comment: Still getting the same error in python 3.9.13.` self._close(async=True)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async` is a keyword in python 3.5+. As you are running this code in python 3.7 assigning a value to a keyword raises a syntax error. If you ran this code in 2.7, it would work just fine.

It looks like this line is not in the most recent version of `paramiko`, which renames this variable to [`async_`](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/sftp_file.py#L84):

```
def _close(self, async_=False):
    # We allow double-close without signaling an error, because real
```

Simply upgrading `paramiko` to the most recent version should solve your problem:

```
sudo pip install -U paramiko
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upgrade paramiko as Bees with Machine Guns uses a specific version. However I actually fixed it by going into that paramiko python file and changing async to be async_ so thanks for the heads up about the keyword change!

Comment: I would be wary of using the version of paramkio you are using with python 3.7 as this is only one of many breaking changes. If you absolutely can't upgrade it, you should should be sure to test it extensively.